# Can Genymotion use snapshots?

Tags: snapshot, genymotion

VirtualBox has the ability to open very fast when using a saved snapshot. Is Genymotion able to use these? I get a compatibility state problem when trying to use the player after restoring a saved state. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it won't work.

The OpenGL acceleration works in this way in Genymotion: All OpenGL instructions are executed outside of the virtual device environnement, in the host OS.

OpenGL is a big state machine. An OpenGL context is kept to execute new OpenGL instructions.

When you do a snapshot, only memory inside the virtual device is kept, the OpenGL context of the host OS is lost. And this context will be necessary to keep the device running after restoring the snapshot.

It is probably for the same reason the Android SDK emulator doesn't allow snapshots when GPU acceleration is activated.